# Can A system rotate when only a part of the system is rotating but not the entire System?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

For Eg-There is a setup of a boy standing on a Platform holding an umbrella .The axis of the Umbrella coincides with that of the platform .The boy starts to spin the umbrella with a certain angular velocity .Now the angular Momentum of the Umbrella is $$Iw$$ but is there any angular momentum of the Umbrella+ boy + platform system since the boy and platform are not rotating.

Comment: Isn't the answer in your question? "Can A system rotate when (...) not the entire System [rotates]?" If it doesn't rotate... it doesn't....

Either I don't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

There are no external torques on the umbrella+boy+platform system; there are plenty of internal torques (just apply Newton's Third Law, accounting for the static friction between the boy's feet and the platform), but there are no torques that come from outside the system. Therefore, conservation of momentum dictates that the umbrella+boy+platform system has as much angular momentum as it started with. Since you have not specified any initial conditions, it's not possible to determine how much angular momentum the system starts with, but whatever that value is, it remains the same throughout this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From your phrasing of the question, I take it that the angular momentum of the system was zero to start with. The law of conservation of angular momentum states that the total angular momentum of an isolated system is constant. Therefore, when the boy starts spinning the umbrella, something else in the system needs to start spinning in the opposite direction to cancel the angular momentum.

What all this means is that either a) your scenario does not obey the laws of physics because the both boy and platform can not remain stationary simultaneously. Or b) you failed to take into consideration additional parts of the system. For instance, Earth itself, which normally absorbs any extra angular momentum in most real scenarios (we don't see it gain any rotation because it is so large that any extra angular momentum we give it amounts to essentially nothing).

In short, the angular momentum of the full system is the same as that after anything happens. Giving one part of a system some angular momentum is only achieved by giving the same amount in the other direction to another part of the system. That is an indisputable fact.